# Can empty lines between code lines decrease the performance of a program in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

I am working on C# ASP.NET, and I have a web page of approximately 10120 lines. I have put more than 2000 blank lines in between the source code lines for my better understanding.

Will it affect to the performance of the web page?

Comment: If you have 10k source lines in a single file you have a much bigger problem to worry about... Anyway whitespace won't impact performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't have any effect on your page—compilers remove whitespace/comments from the generated binary.

However, if the whitespace/comments is sent to the browser, say in the CSS content or in JavaScript, then you could be sending more data to the browser than what the browser actually needs (i.e., you're wasting bandwidth).

The solution for this is to [minify](http://jscompress.com/) your files.

Answer (score 4):

It has no effect on the compiled code.  It's a good thing to use whitespace as it can greatly improve *readability*.

Comment: yes this is very nice thing, but what about the performance during compilation ?

Comment: Probably not measurable, but I can't see why would you care.

Comment: yeah you are right, i need not to be worry about this not measurable performance affect.

Comment: just my 0.02$, the empty lines decrease the amount of code that fits on one screen so it can also decrease code readability. It is highly dependent on the project and matter of taste.